# Blazor server side or client side, towards backend DB

Tags: design, c#, web-development

I'm wondering, although as I think both options are possible.
Currently, there are two versions for Blazor projects in visual studio 2019.
If you want to connect to a backend DB then there are two project solution options:

- a "Hosted Blazor WebAssembly app" project.
- a "Blazer server-side" project.

Both can handle connections towards a SQL backend.
Now I kinda wonder (starting a big and complex DB project), what and why would you choose one above the other what's your experience with it?
I'm wondering about:

- How about coding, and future software version updates.
  I wouldn't mind big changes in how we code.
  But it should be good maintainable in practice,
  So doing software updates, it must be debuggable,
  No hex errors when supporting client problems (which might be coding bugs).
  Just asking others **what codes with is most maintainable** currently?
- What is **currently the most modern though safe road** to travel with these two Blazor versions.
  Are there maybe risks I should be aware of if I choose one above the other.
  did some of you had a bad experience?.
- Is there a public roadmap plan from MS what their direction is with .net core.
  Cause over the last years there has been a lot of changes in .net core.
  And I don't like to bett on the wrong horse here.

Comment: good question, what is the state of play with blazor atm? last time i checked webasm wasnt supported on  chrome?

Comment: @ewan i guess you checked that many years ago then.

Comment: Ewan is making a good point with all kind of these days mobile devices, though my customer base will be using normal office client Windows PC's. ChromeOS might become popular however as alike noted by mr Zach that specific case seams supported now. (accoording to the white papers) its not something i have experience with.

Comment: Pretty sure direct access to a database like SQL Server is not possible in a web assembly project; you will have to go through a layer running on a server, like a web API.

Comment: @TGnat I had to verify there seems to exist a package, out of the box your right.  Install-Package ExpressionPowerTools.Serialization.EFCore.AspNetCore  But still i think its adviseable to have some serverside stack and client stack keeping signalR in between. or web API. Probaply a nightmare to debug as client-web app.